# What good javascript datagrids exisits to use with knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js

Im looking for a good datagrid that works nice together with knockoutjs.

My backend is a webapi service providing json data, and frontend is using knockoutjs for MVVM. Im looking for a nice datagrid that makes it easy to post updates back to the server as updated elements from the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Try KoGrid  https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid, there is simple example  http://ericmbarnard.github.com/KoGrid/examples/SimpleExample.html